# How to detect movement of table on WatchOS?

Tags: apple-watch, wkinterfacetable, watchos

In table cell, I have a label that I have to update every second and this makes scroll very laggy... If I can now that user is making the table move, I could stop the timer that updates all the cells. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this is not supported on WatchOS 2.